# How to get started with Metro Website development

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, web, microsoft-metro

Are there any microsoft frameworks+tutorials on how to create a website that is conform to their Metro UI principals?

I can find all kinds of frameworks/toolkits CSS/LESS based, but nothing backed up by microsoft. I assume microsoft would benefit from providing a toolkit so that more and more website "look like their windows 8".

I have a webapplication on MVC4 (+html5+css3). Should I place my bets on some opensource toolkit (which seems to lack decent documentation/example code) or will microsoft throw something fancy our way?

I also checked NuGet stuff but there seems nothing (yet).

many thanks!

Comment: Metro is a desktop UI metaphor, not a website one.

Comment: So you wouldnt recommend metro for web?

Comment: Well, you will not find any frameworks or tutorials for metro on the web because of that. Personally, I don't see the point of trying to use a desktop UI on the web. Make it a usable website instead.

Comment: Hmm, how disappointing. Thought the worlds of desktop, tablets and web were intergrating. Same look&feel on every device. But k, thx for the insights.

Comment: Well, consider how out of place a "metro" website would look on an Android or iOS device...

Comment: Fair enough. Although we build a webapp used in corporate environments. Safe to say it's all microsoft anyway. But I guess I got my answer: MS doesn't provide a toolkit for Metro for Web. I'll dive in metro-css or bootmetro and see how they work out. PS: I also don't think the modern "metro UI" will be dissatisfying on any other OS/device, it feels natural, bright, clear. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: I'd look at Outlook.com;  That seems like a Metro themed web site.  I'm not sure I agree with the out of place; what web pages DO look like the OS of the device the user is running?  Apps sure, but websites?  I don't think it would be a problem for users of Apple / Android to vista a "metro style" website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, the Microsoft resources are not easy to find or very well organized. This is the best official resource I have bookmarked:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229565

It's sort of a 'table of contents' for deeper information like:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150600